# Analyzing PHP Scripts to Identify Source of Intermittent Website Performance Issue

Tags: centos, php

My site has been getting some hits on performance as of recently. About half the time, my site will run smoothly, while at other times it loads ridiculously slow.

My server is running on CentOS 5. I run the command top -c to check what is the issue.
The process that's almost always on top is php-cgi, which is normal I believe.
However, sometimes there would be several php-cgi processes and/or it will spike up to an accumulated ~100% CPU usage for a few seconds, then go back to normal.

Is there a way to find out what is causing this specifically?

Comment: Read your log files.

Comment: The best is profiling tools: xhprof or xdebug. It would provide full information about which functions are take this time to execute.

Comment: My log files don't say anything regarding server load/script issues. Just some missing images which I fixed but I doubt missing images are causing load issues.
@Navern I'm looking at them and it seems like they work per script. The issue is that I'm running vBulletin software. vBulletin has SEVERAL scripts.

Comment: sure you can add xhprof to EVERY script with .htaccess
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/file or if you are running php-cgi with php.ini auto_prepend_file = /path/to/file.